python3-catkin-pkg : Conflicts: catkin but 0.8.10-7 is to be installed
I am working on my Final Year Robotics Project, relatively new to Robotics. I am using ROS2 on Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish. I want to use RPLIDAR package and hector_slam package for my project. For using them, I have to create a ROS workspace (as suggested, correct me if any easier alternatives are available). I was suggested to create a catkin or colcon workspace.
Let me explain what happened when I tried to create both of these workspaces:
Trying to setup a Catkin workspace
I ran
sudo apt install catkin

encountered the following errors:
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-catkin-pkg : Conflicts: catkin but 0.8.10-7 is to be installed
 python3-catkin-pkg-modules : Conflicts: catkin but 0.8.10-7 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ammar@ammar-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB:~$

Trying to setup a Colcon workspace
mkdir ws
cd ws
mkdir src

The output was:
Summary: 0 packages finished [1.64s]

Then I cloned the rplidar repository:
cd src
git clone https://github.com/robopeak/rplidar_ros.git

Output:
Cloning into 'rplidar_ros'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 502, done.
remote: Total 502 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 502
Receiving objects: 100% (502/502), 412.04 KiB | 393.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (277/277), done

Then I executed:
cd ..
colcon build

Output (problematic):
Starting >>> rplidar_ros
--- stderr: rplidar_ros                         
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findcatkin.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "catkin", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "catkin" with any
  of the following names:

    catkinConfig.cmake
    catkin-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "catkin" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "catkin_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "catkin"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


---
Failed   <<< rplidar_ros [3.93s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 0 packages finished [4.41s]
  1 package failed: rplidar_ros
  1 package had stderr output: rplidar_ros

Can you please:

Specify is there any alternative of these two methods that are more well-suited for my case?
Is it suggested if I uninstall the python3 from my system, and re-install the catkin package with sudo apt install catkin? Because (correct me if I am wrong) catkin package of python3 is conflicting with the catkin package we are trying to install globally?
If not, what will be the solution, to successfully setup the catkin or colcon workspace?

